# Given vectors u,v and w find the cosine angle between two cross products.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given vectors
u = (1 , 5, -3)
; v = (0 , 2, -1)
; w = (1, 1, 1)

I'm asked to find the cosine of the angle between the two vectors $v \times w$ and $u \times v$.

I did the cross product of the vectors (sorry if it's not the righ term, I'm french and translating)

I obtained :
$v \times w$  = (3, -1, -2) and $u \times v$ = (1, 1, 2)

I then need to use the cosine formula which is the dot product of $v \times w$ and $u \times v$ divided by the product of their norms?

the answer is supposed to either be

- A. $2/21$
- B. $\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{21}$
- C. $-1/\sqrt{7}$
- D. $-1/ \sqrt{21}$
- E. $-1/21$
- F. $2/\sqrt{7}$

Any help is much appreciated.

- edit: I keep getting the answer of -4/(sqrt(96)*sqrt(6))
  I can't really figure out where I'm going wrong.
- edit2: did it again and i'm at -2/sqrt(84).

I just can't seem to land on a correct answer when I use the cosine formula... :S

Comment: You know the two vectors, and you know what formula you need to get the cosine angle between them. Where is the difficulty?

Comment: Yes, what you are doing is correct and the correct answer is one of the suggested answers.  Do it!

Comment: I'm getting the answer -4/(sqrt(96)sqrt(6)) :S. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong :S

Comment: -1 for formatting, +1 for content.

Answer (score 0):

-2/sqrt(84) is equal to answer D ;)

Comment: wow, thanks, I'm an idiot lol. I hate this no calculator thing. I'm not very good at finding my square roots without it and I did not see that 2x2x21 = 84 lol. Thanks

Comment: To avoid taking square roots, you could compare the square of your answer with the squares of the choices.